# Execute Word Document VBA macro using VB Form

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm creating a VB Form that help to select a word file and then I can use another button action to identify the Content Controls tags from that document. The problem is how can I  run any vba word macro using Vb Form? Below is code -

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\%username%\Documents"
    fd.Filter = "Word Documents|*.doc;*.docx"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = fd.FileName
        PathLabel.Text = fd.FileName
        MsgBox("You have selected file -" & fd.FileName)

    End If
End Sub


Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk_1(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

End Sub
```

Word Macro -

```
Sub GetCCs()
    Dim d As Document
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim sr As Range
    Dim srs As StoryRanges
    For Each sr In d.StoryRanges
        For Each cc In sr.ContentControls
            Debug.Print cc.Title
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Apologies if I'm doing anything wrong here as I'm pretty new to this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project and module to reference your macro. i.e....

```
Call prjMyProject.modMyModule.GetCCs
```

If your form is in the same project you can likely get by with:

```
Call GetCCs
```

- Note - your macro must be in a project that is loaded (i.e. attached template, active Add-In)